# Read list formatted data from file in python

Tags: python, list

I know this must be a simple question for you all. I have textfile with test cases written in below list format,

```
[["arg1", "arg2", "arg3"], "Fail"]

[["arg1", "arg2", "arg4"], "Pass"]
```

. . .

And I want to read this file in a list such a that, I can print `list1[1] => "Fail".`

thanks for your help.

Comment: You need something like: `["arg1", "arg2", "arg3"]` => `"Fail"` ?

Comment: No, I was expecting output like, output_list[1] is "Fail".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval()` to safe convert the string line to a python expression

Example:

```
import ast

with open('list.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

data = [ast.literal_eval(line) for line in lines]

for item in data:
    print(item[1])
```

Comment: Thanks, Sergey Tolokonnikov, I was trying this module but was doing some silly mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

**Assumptions**

- You have a `.txt` file.
- Format of a line is `[["arg1", "arg2", "arg3",...etc.], "Fail/Pass"]`

Approach is to use regex to find all text between double quotes and append to the list. The last one is taken as "Fail/Pass" and rest of them are args.

```py
import re

result = []

with open('text.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        match = re.findall("\"(.*?)\"",line.strip())
        result.append([match[:-1],match[-1]])

print(result)
print(result[0][0])
print(result[0][1])
```

---

Sample Input `.txt` file

```
[["arg1", "arg2", "arg3","arg4"], "Fail"]
[["arg1", "arg2", "arg4"], "Pass"]
```

Output

```
[[['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', 'arg4'], 'Fail'], [['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg4'], 'Pass']]
['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', 'arg4']
Fail
```

Comment: Thanks Ajay. I liked your approach.

Answer (score 2):

Just use eval , its internal python function and you dont need libraries.

Example:

```
lists = []
line1 = '[["arg1", "arg2", "arg3"], "Fail"]'
line2 = '[["arg1", "arg2", "arg4"], "Pass"]'
# Evaluate Lines
exLine1 = eval(line1)
exLine2 = eval(line2)
# Append Lines to lists
lists.append(exLine1)
lists.append(exLine2)
# Testing Example of your use case
print(str(exLine1[1] == "Fail"))
```

Just Convert this example to for loop you are using and it will be fast and simple

Comment: You must never use `eval()` in python. Read [Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1):

I would do like this.

sample myfile.txt:

```
[["arg1", "arg2", "arg3"], "Fail"]
[["arg1", "arg2", "arg4"], "Pass"]
```

Main python file.

```
file1 = open('myfile.txt', 'r') 
count = 0

while True: 
    count += 1

    # Get next line from file 
    list = file1.readline()
    if not list: 
        break
    #convert string to list
    res = list.strip('][').split(', ') 
    print(res[1])
```

After reading the file line by line, Convert the string of list into list by using split.

Comment: Hello Deepak, thanks for your try. 
But you are reading all values in one list whereas I need list format as is in text file.

Comment: Please refer this link for converting string representation of list to list
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-a-string-representation-of-list-into-list/

Answer (score 1):

You can hack together some pretty simple string manipulation code, as everyone is providing here. I've done it simply like this:

```
text = """
[["arg1", "arg2", "arg3"], "Fail"]
[["arg1", "arg2", "arg4"], "Pass"]
"""

for line in text.strip().splitlines():
    line = line.replace('[', '')
    line = line.replace(']', '')
    print line.split(',')[-1].strip()
```

It's not pretty but you can do it plenty of better ways if you're looking to do this is production.

Comment: Nice try ev350. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like below:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as test_file:
content = test_file.readlines()

print(content)
print(type(content))

for data in content:
    print(ast.literal_eval(data)[1])

print("*" * 30)
for i in range(1, len(content)+1):
    print(i)
```

output:

```
index:  0

[["arg1", "arg2", "arg3"], "Fail"]

index: 1

[["arg1", "arg2", "arg4"], "Pass"]
```

---

```
1
2
```

Comment: Thanks, Nasreen for trying, but this solution is not giving me proper elements.

Answer (score 0):

What about this code example from [link](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-lists-to-a-file-in-python/):

```
# load additional module
import pickle

with open('listfile.data', 'rb') as filehandle:
    # read the data as binary data stream
    placesList = pickle.load(filehandle)
```

Comment: I tried but it's not working... thanks for your help.